# Rust collect iterator to new vector when randomly selecting elements between two vectors

Tags: rust, iterator

Given two same length `Vec<u8>`, trying to select an element from each index with a given probability `p: f32`, as follows,

```
fn select(xs: &Vec<u8>, ys: &Vec<u8>, p: f32) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    xs
        .iter()
        .zip(ys.iter())
        .map(|(a, b)| if rng.gen_range(0.0..1.0) < p { a } else { b })
        .collect()
}
```

However,

```
value of type `Vec<u8>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&u8>`
```

How to `collect` an iterator into a new vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy your values for example by dereferencing `*` or using `&` in the pattern<sup>1</sup>:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
fn shuffle(xs: &[u8], ys: &[u8], p: f32) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    std::iter::zip(xs, ys)
        .map(|(x, &y)| if rng.gen_range(0.0..1.0) < p { *x } else { y })
        .collect()
}
```

For most `FromIterator` implementations the item iterated over has to be the same as the one that ends up in the collection, but you're iterating over `&u8` and want to end up with just `u8` in the collection.

Other changes:

- `&Vec<u8>` → `&[u8]` as it's more general,
- `xs.iter().zip(ys.iter())` as that's really not very readable, if you zip more than once `use std::iter` and `iter::zip(xs, ys)` else just use that function directly
- use `x` and `y` for values of `xs` and `ys` respectively

---

<sup>1) Obviously in your code just stick to one of the ways, just showing both posibilities here for illustration.</sup>

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but I believe another option to mention might be `.copied()` to convert from iterator of `&T` (`where T: Copy`) to iterator of `T` ahead of time. Not a big difference either way, but it's *slightly* more explicit. For something that doesn't implement `Copy`, but does implement `Clone`, there's `.cloned()`, which is even more useful to my mind (since adding `.clone()` calls within the callback clutters things, so it's nice to get that out of the way ahead of time).